# Page limit for IEEE JBHI (including reference or not)

Tags: journals, paper-submission, ieee

On the page of IEEE JBHI (https://www.embs.org/jbhi/prepare-and-submit-your-manuscript/), it says:

> PAGE CHARGES. Review papers that exceed ten (10) pages incur mandatory page charges. Regular papers that exceed eight (8) pages will incur mandatory overlength page charges. For papers that are 8 pages or fewer: only voluntary page charges ($110/page); 9–10 pages: mandatory page charges ($250/page for pages 9 and 10); 11 pages and beyond: $350/page.
>
> PAGE LIMIT. The page limit is 12 pages for regular paper and 14 pages for review papers including supplementary material. The page limit must be implemented in both original submissions and revised papers.
>
> MANDATORY PAGE CHARGES. The author(s) or his/her/their company or institution will be billed for all pages according to the Page Charge policy. For regular papers, the rate for pages 9 and 10 is $250 per page, and the rate for page 11 and beyond is $350 per page. Payment of these charges is not negotiable or voluntary. Further, submission by the author of his/her manuscript to this publication signifies acceptance of the requirement to pay mandatory pages charges. The Publisher holds the right to withhold publication of the current submission or any future submissions from the author(s) if this charge is not honored. To avoid incurring mandatory page charges, the author(s) are strongly advised to practice economy in the original manuscript submission and restraint in preparation of the final manuscript following peer review.

So, what is the page limit for a paper without any additional fee? I presume it's 8 pages, but is it with or without the reference or supplementary material section?

Comment: Why not drop a note to an editor? Let him or her know you’ve read the information above but are confused.

Comment: Thank you, I already sent an email with the queries.

Comment: Best of luck to you. And when you learn what you’ll learn, consider posting an update with that info.

Comment: This depends on whether you have a 'Review' or 'Regular' paper.  The page limit includes everything.

Answer (score 1):

From the editor office,

1. Is the 8-page limit with or without the references and biography section?
   **The page limit includes the references. The biography section is not required.**
2. Is it possible to include supplementary materials in the paper? If yes, will it be considered in the page limit?
   **It is possible. However supplementary material is added at the end of your manuscript (after the references section) and is included in the page limit.**